# Downloaded an app from App Store but it never appeared on my iPod touch

Tags: ios-appstore, clash-of-clans

I was downloading Clash of Clans. I clicked the download button and it did everything normal. But when it finished, the app never showed up on my iPod touch. So then, I decided to delete it and try again, but there was no deleting option that I could find.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you use the home screen's search feature to try and find it? What OS is running on your iPod? What generation of iPod Touch is it?

Comment: After you downloaded from the AppStore, if you open the game again in the AppStore, do you see a "Open" button?

Comment: yea i tried searching it. And yes the Open button is there, but when I click it, nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Power off your device and try opening the game first after the device starts from a clean boot.

If that doesn't work, you'll have to find the app on the home screen and delete it.

Here is Apple's KB on troubleshooting apps that don't open:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1702

Feel free to ask a second question if you can't use that document to solve your Clash of Clans issue.